# Push to remote master when current master is behind

Tags: git

**Problem:**

I did something with `revert` and "checkouting to specific commits" and now my *local master* is behind *remote master*.

I assume, that i'm in this situation right now(but not sure):

```
97f889e(origin/changes, changes)---some commit---some commit---current remote master
        \ ______0d0d2f(HEAD -> master) (!! I"M HERE !!)
```

**I want:**

All i want is `97f889e` or `0d0d2f` to be in remote master. I don't care about "some commit" and "current remote master"

**My thoughts:**
So, i'm at `0d0d2f` atm, and it's behind.
Git advises me to `git pull`, but if i pull, i loose changes. I can't to `git stash` to save changes, because: `No local changes to save`.

P.S. `97f889e` was not a `master` branch but i merged it into master(git shows this commit in `changes` branch though)

P.P.S `git push --force` returns

> remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
>   To gitlab.ostrovok.ru:rnd/ypc-forecast.git
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Comment: It sounds like you want to force push?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to  override the remote repository and loose the `some commit` you should

```
git push --force
```

Do note that this is considered dangerous as it overrides the remote history. It is not recommended because other branches and forks might be using `some commit` already. You might want to prefer `git rebase` to integrate the commits ahead.

Comment: `remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
To gitlab.ostrovok.ru:rnd/ypc-forecast.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

Comment: There is a server-side hook to prevent force push. It's not uncommon, if you insist on force pushing you must disable this on server-side.

Comment: do you mean, i need to change repository settings?

Comment: Most likely yes, I'm not familiar with Gitlab but somewhere there must be an option to manage hooks. If not, the hook can be configured as part of git installation on the server.